# Using pandas dataframe with Scipy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

Assuming a dataframe, *df*,  using pandas in the size of n x m.

I would like to perfom linear algebra operation on *df*.

Until now, I was unable to find a way to perfom directly linear algebra on *df*. What i was able to find is how to convert *df* from pandas format to Numpy using:

```
A = DataFrame.as_matrix
```

then I can simpy do

```
linalg.inv(A)
```

Is there a direct way of performing linear operation in Scipy using pandas dataframe? for example:

```
linalg.inv(df)
```

The reason I would like to use the linear algebra operation from scipy instead of Numpy is based on:

> In any case, SciPy contains more fully-featured versions of the linear algebra modules, as well as many other numerical algorithms. If you are doing scientific computing with python, you should probably install both NumPy and SciPy. Most new features belong in SciPy rather than NumPy.

from [What-is-the-difference-between-NumPy-and-SciPy](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-NumPy-and-SciPy)

Comment: Both `pandas` and `scipy` are built on `numpy`.  Most `scipy` code assumes inputs are arrays, or can be converted to such. `scipy ` `inv` converts the input to a `numpy` array (with `np.asarray`).  If a dataframe works in a scipy function it's because it can be converted to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use it on your DataFrames.

Demo:

```
In [111]: from scipy.linalg import inv

In [112]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,5), columns=list('abcde'))

In [113]: df
Out[113]:
          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.619086  0.229390  0.361611  0.857177  0.274983
1  0.389630  0.689562  0.687043  0.388781  0.781168
2  0.702920  0.253870  0.881173  0.858378  0.363035
3  0.007022  0.571111  0.408729  0.708862  0.042882
4  0.876747  0.170775  0.499824  0.929295  0.762971

In [114]: inv(df)
Out[114]:
array([[ 5.67652746,  1.54854922, -0.21927114, -3.04884324, -3.35567433],
       [ 4.32996215,  1.99787442, -1.18579234, -0.9802008 , -2.98677673],
       [-2.43833426, -0.29287732,  2.11691208,  0.34655505,  0.1519223 ],
       [-1.92398165, -1.43903773, -0.22722582,  1.96404685,  2.16451337],
       [-3.55144126, -0.28205091, -0.59264783,  1.10366465,  3.09938364]])
```

PS i used `Pandas 0.19.2` and `SciPy 0.18.1` for this demo.

**UPDATE:** if you want to get a DataFrame as a result:

```
In [4]: pd.DataFrame(inv(df), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
Out[4]:
          a         b         c         d         e
0  5.676507  1.548541 -0.219275 -3.048828 -3.355657
1  4.329938  1.997865 -1.185791 -0.980187 -2.986760
2 -2.438323 -0.292872  2.116913  0.346547  0.151914
3 -1.923971 -1.439034 -0.227226  1.964040  2.164506
4 -3.551428 -0.282045 -0.592647  1.103655  3.099373
```

Comment: once i do inv(df) in your example, i get Numpy array, correct?

Comment: @Eagle, i can't say whether it's correct or not... The question is - what do you want to achieve? ;-)